# как выполнить операцию сложения для глобальной переменной внутри функции

Tags: python-3.x, функции, global-variables

```
row=3
id=3

def KeyMove(matrix:list, ind0:vars, ind1:vars, math_symbols:str, line:vars 'принимает или row или id', ind_number:int, switch_coor=True):
        global row, id, plane1
        system('cls')

        matrix[ind0][ind1] = 0

        if math_symbols == 'plus':
            line += 1
        elif math_symbols == 'minus':
            line -= 1
        
        try:
            AddPlayer()
        except IndexError:
            line = ind_number
        
        if switch_coor is True:
            print(ind0,ind1)
        elif switch_coor is False:
            pass
        VisualMatrix(matrix)
        return line, ind_number

KeyMove(matrix=plane1, ind0=row, ind1=id, math_symbols='minus', line=row, ind_number=7)
```

Проблема в том, что `line+=1` или `line-=1` не меняют значение глобальных переменных `row, id`. я нашёл два решения проблемы, но 1. мне нужно чтобы я мог записать любой аргумент в `line` и 2. мне нужно чтобы решение проблемы оставалось в **функции**, а не выходила за её пределы, по типу сначала `func():...`, а потом `a=func(5)`. так же это касается `except IndexError: line = ind_number`, но если решится первая проблема то и второй касаться смысла нету.

Answer (score 0):

Примитивное значение передается по значению, иначе нельзя. Можно передавать какой то объект, например список, тогда он будет передаваться по ссылке и значения изменятся
Например

```
row=[3]

def SomeFun(val):
  val[0]+=1

SomeFun(row)
row[0] == 4
```

Comment: можете напомнить, а каким методом можно список в число преобразовать?

Comment: благодарю за помощь! а то часа 4 целый день голову ломал и узнал много всего, но не ответ :)

Comment: просто по индексу берете число из списка. можно переприсвоить переменную row = row[0]

Comment: могу добавить к комментариям, что преобразовать список с одним элементом в число, можно с помощью `max()` или `min()`